# Delete files older than 5 days as well as in all subfolders

Tags: directory, delete, rm

I need to delete all files older than 5 days in all subfolders, but not the folders themselves. I know the command:

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

But how can I tell Ubuntu to check in all subfolders, yet never delete the folders themselves. Will I need a -maxdepth 5 somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: `-type f` will find only files, not folders.

Comment: Will it automatically check subfolders?

Comment: Yes, that is the default behaviour of `find`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, will test! Can you make your comment a answer so I can upvote once tested?

Comment: Someone jumped in before me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, don't give a glob to `find` (no `files*`), just give it the parent directory (`/path/to/`). It will deal with recursing into it and finding all files. Next, `rm` will never delete directories, so you don't need to worry about that either. Still, the simplest way is:

```
find /path/to/ -type f -mtime +5 -delete
```

Note the `-type f` which tells `find` to only look at files and the `-delete` which, well, deletes them. This is more efficient than calling a separate `rm` for each result.

Comment: `find /path/to/ -type f -mtime +5` will match files starting from 6 days old, i am not sure if that's what OP wants. For 5 days or more, `find /path/to/ -type f -mtime +4`

Comment: @heemayl good point, but since the OP said "*older* than 5 days", I assume that's what they wanted.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use

```
find /path/to -type f -mtime 5+ -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Edited answer for subfolder use

Comment: What's the advantage of `-exec rm {} \;` over `-delete`? As far as I can tell it'll do the same thing but slower because it spawns a new `rm` process for each match. You could use `-exec rm {} +` to invoke `rm` on multiple files at once but that's still one more fork+exec than necessary.

Comment: The keyword is "also". Didn't know about the performance.

Comment: Sure. That's why I didn't vote to delete your answer but ask about its benefits. I still think it's suboptimal.